# Apache Beam infer schema using NamedTuple (Python)

Tags: python, schema, apache-beam, namedtuple

I am quite new to apache beam and I am wondering how to infer schema to a pcollection using namedtuple.

The example from the documentation [Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#inferring-schemas) states:

```py
class Transaction(typing.NamedTuple):
  bank: str
  purchase_amount: float

pc = input | beam.Map(lambda ...).with_output_types(Transaction)
```

I tried to implement similar thing but reading from a parquet file first

```py
from apache_beam import coders
from typing import NamedTuple
import apache_beam as beam


class TestSchema(NamedTuple):
    company_id: int
    is_company: bool
    company_created_datetime: str
    company_values: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    coders.registry.register_coder(TestSchema, coders.RowCoder)
    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
        record = pipeline | "Read Parquet" >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet("test.parquet").with_output_types(TestSchema) \
                          | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)

        pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
```

And I am getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'company_id' [while running 'Read Parquet/ParDo(_ArrowTableToRowDictionaries)']`

Also without the `.with_output_types(TestSchema)` I can see the data fine which looks like this

```
{'company_id': 3, 'is_company': True, 'company_created_datetime': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 8, 13, 2, 26, 573511), 'company_values': 'test value'}
```

I am using python 3.8 and beam 2.37.0

Am I missing something? any help would be appreciated (stack trace below).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 346, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 348, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 817, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SdfProcessSizedElements.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 826, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SdfProcessSizedElements.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1206, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process_with_sized_restriction
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 698, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 836, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1361, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 707, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 708, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1200, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 841, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1361, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 214, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 178, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 211, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 250, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1425, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1436, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 207, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 246, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.estimate_size
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1610, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.RowCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'company_id' [while running 'Read Parquet/ParDo(_ArrowTableToRowDictionaries)']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after some research on beam schema and digging in the source code I finally found the solution. It looks like you need to convert every single value in the pcollection to NamedTuple and later apply a type hint.

```
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    record = pipeline | "Read Parquet" >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet("test.parquet") \
                      | "Transform to NamedTuple" beam.Map(lambda x: TestSchema(**x)).with_output_types(TestSchema) \
                      | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
```

Comment: Yes; ReadFromParquet produces dicts, not named tuples. On the other hand, type hints don't change the contents, just inform Beam of its expected type.

Comment: FYI, you may be able to elide the explicit with_output_types and let Beam infer it from your lambda.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!  Yes, it would be nice if `with_output_types` actually performed some sort of transformation. But it is entirely just type hinting.  What I have done in my pipelines is created a `PTransform` that does both the ingestion and conversion to the desired object in one step.  That way, it still "feels like" you're able to read from source and "infer" into the proper class / type in one step. (It is explicit, not inferred, but still _feels_ like one simple step...)