# Apache Beam PCollection Schema (converting to Dataframe)

Tags: dataframe, google-bigquery, schema, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to grab some data from BigQuery, update a couple of columns using Python, and then write it to another location. I'm using Apache Beam (via Google Dataflow) to do this.

Once I have the data from BigQuery as a PCollection, I want to convert it to a Beam Dataframe so I can update the relevant columns.

However, in order to do so, I need ensure the PCollection object is schema-aware. Even following the Beam documentation, I'm having trouble doing so.

I've tried following the pattern discussed in this post: [Apache Beam infer schema using NamedTuple (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71629200/apache-beam-infer-schema-using-namedtuple-python) and here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#inferring-schemas

Schema Named Tuple Code:

```
class TestSchema(typing.NamedTuple):
  entry_id: str
  entry_name: int
  user_id: str
  user_entry: str
  document: str

coders.registry.register_coder(TestSchema, coders.RowCoder)
```

Here's some test pipeline code in my `run` function (some boilerplace ommitted):

```
with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv) as p:
        pcoll = (p | 'read_bq_view' >> 
        beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=BIGQUERY_SELECT_QUERY,use_standard_sql=True) 
        | "schematize" >> beam.Map(lambda x: TestSchema(**x)).with_output_types(TestSchema)
        | beam.Map(print)
        )
```

When I run this, I get:

```
NameError: name 'TestSchema' is not defined [while running 'schematize-ptransform-49']
```

What am I missing here? The class TestSchema exists and is in scope (it's at the top level of my file). I've tried using the traditional NamedTuple syntax in case I was messing up the `class` syntax, but I get the same error.

Comment: Where is the TestSchema defined? In the same file? If not, you need to import it. Otherwise, your code looks fine and should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/), you can use `beam.Row` in this case, example :

```py
def test_pipeline(self):
    with TestPipeline() as p:
        inputs = {
            'entry_id': 'ffff',
            'entry_name': 4,
            'user_id': 'ddddd',
            'user_entry': 'dDDFFF',
            'document': 'VVBBB'
        }

        entries = (p
                   | 'Inputs' >> beam.Create([inputs])
                   | 'ToRows' >> beam.Map(lambda user_entry: beam.Row(
                    entry_id=user_entry['entry_id'],
                    entry_name=user_entry['entry_name'],
                    user_id=user_entry['user_id'],
                    user_entry=user_entry['user_entry'],
                    document=user_entry['document']
                )))

        df = to_dataframe(entries)

        # Deferred DataFrames can also be converted back to schema'd PCollections
        collection = to_pcollection(df, include_indexes=False)

        collection | 'Print' >> beam.Map(print)
```

- I created a mock for input to simulate the data retrieved from `BigQuery`
- I used `beam.Row` in a `Map` to add a schema to the `PCollection`
- Convert the `PCollection` to `Dataframe`